# Convert minutes -> hh:mm. Shortest code possible (one-liner?)

Tags: javascript

This is just for fun. What would be the shortest code replacement for a function that converts (negative and positive) minutes into the format hh:mm? 
Examples: 90 minutes -> 1:30, 0 -> "", -90 -> -1:30, 1 -> 0:01.

I do have my own function, that works like a charm, but perhaps you find yourself challenged to write a one-liner, that does the same thing like my somewhat awkward 5-liner. Please don't include any third party lib.

```
function convertMinutesToHourStr(minutes) {
        if (minutes === 0)
            return "";
        var minutesStr = Math.abs(minutes) % 60 < 10 ? "0" + Math.abs(minutes) % 60 : Math.abs(minutes) % 60;
        var str = parseInt(Math.abs(minutes) / 60) + ":" + minutesStr;
        return minutes < 0 ? "-" + str : str;
    }
```

Again: this is just for the challenge to write the shortest possible code for a simple task and goes to all those incredibly smart people out there. This is not to get sth to work. Yes, I know, there's a bunch of similar questions, so please don't say "duplicate" and downgrade. If you feel offended by this question, just ignore it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it: **Edit: Don't use this. See below**

```
function convertMinutesToHourStr(minutes) {
    return parseInt(minutes/60) + ":" + ([1e15] + Math.abs(minutes % 60)).slice(-2);
}
```

The only downside to this is 0 minutes would output 0:00.

**Edit:**

```
function convertMinutesToHourStr(minutes) {
    return minutes ? (minutes<0 ? "-" : "") + parseInt(Math.abs(minutes/60)) + ":" + ([1e15] + Math.abs(minutes % 60)).slice(-2) : "";
}
```

Will output `""` for an input of 0. Non-numeric inputs will break it though.

Comment: Given the "truthiness" of non-zero numbers, you can get the same behavior for your minutes == 0 by just using minutes alone as the logical comparison

Comment: Wonderful. This is poetry!

Comment: Out of curiosity: why `[1e15] + Math.abs(minutes % 60)` and not just: `"1" + Math.abs(minutes % 60)`? Is there a trick with an array?

Comment: He's doing it to get a bunch of zeros for padding, but it's more than needed since `minutes % 60` will always return either one or two characters. He could do `("0" + Math.abs(...)).slice(-2)` instead

Comment: He could also shorten it with `~~(minutes/60)` instead of `parseInt`, assuming `minutes` will always fit within a signed 32-bit range. And of course shorter variable naming.

Comment: @strah because I wasn't thinking about it. It was a solution I used in the past for another function.

Comment: It doesn't work for -1. It returns 0:01, but should return -0:01

Comment: @Bernie, you're right. It won't work for anything between -59 and -1. I'll put up a fix.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my attempt. I like destroying my variables as the function progresses. If you show them mercy you tempt rebellion.

```
function convertMinutesToHourStr(minutes) {
    return minutes?(minutes<0?"-":"")+(Math.floor((minutes=Math.abs(minutes))/60))+":"+((minutes=minutes%60)>9?minutes:"0"+minutes):"";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Using date.js https://github.com/datejs/Datejs

```
(new Date()).clearTime()
   .addMinutes(minutes)
   .toString('H:mm');
```

or without external libraries

```
new Date(null).setMinutes(minutes);
```

Comment: (Standard) `Date.prototype.toString()` receives no values.